# Possible to modify existing class file using jcodemodel

Tags: java, code-generation, codegen

Is it possible to modify the existing class file using jcodemodel?

if it so, could give me some reference?

kindly reply am in need of it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution for it.
I am now using [JavaParser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/wiki/UsingThisParser#Sample_Usage) instead. it can load a file or create a new one.